# Fluid HTML Framework

Tags: html, css, zooming, fluid-layout

How to place the 'content' in the following code so that it doesn't overlaps the text-box on the right using the Bauhaus fluid framework since on zooming in, the 'content' overlaps the sidebar content!!

```
<div class="container_16">
<div class="grid_16">
    <div class="grid_10" style="float:left;">           
         <p>Content....</p>             
    </div>
            <div class="grid_6" style="float:right">
                 <p>Sidebar content</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use min-width attribute to set minimum width for the container div like below

```
<div class="container_16" style="min-width:250px">
<div class="grid_16">
    <div class="grid_10">           
         <p>Content............</p>             
    </div>
            <div class="grid_6">
                 <p>Sidebar content</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

float removes an elements influence on the positioning of other elements.

instead, you can use the css:

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
```

and,

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
```

accordingly.

Comment: I just figured out , the content in the grid_10 is an image. It was overflowing. I have added the following code and its working fine!
    
    .grid_10{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    }